# Where does django's makemessages keep the list of locales for --all option

Tags: python, django

Django's manage.py makemessages function can be used with the option --all (or -a), which makes po files for all the locales that have been previously given to makemessages as -l options. Does anyone know where does makemessages get this list? I know it's not from the LANGUAGES tuple in the project settings module because locale folders for languages in there only show up after I explicitly add them at least once with `makemessages -l <locale>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does take the locales from `LANGUAGES` in settings.py

if you `makemessages -all` or `makemessages -a`, it creates locale folders for ALL languages which are given in `LANGUAGES`

Quote from docs:

```
Use the --all or -a option to update the message files for all available languages.
```

in Django, as far as I know, `all available languages` can be only given thru `LANGUAGES` in settings.py

Comment: So it does. My bad. Not sure how it got into my head that wasn't the case. Thanks for the help